# Beveling creates a new face?

Tags: bezier-curves, faces, bevel

I have started to bevel my goggle edges and am running into a problem. The model seems fine but when I bevel it a new face appears on the front?! Is this due to the top piece being a Boolean modifier for the bottom piece?
Here it what it looks like before beveling:
[image]
These are the faces I want to bevel:
[image]
And this is what happens:
[image]
[image]
What am I doing wrong? Please help! Thank you!

Comment: It looks like you are also trying bevel that small edge on the sides creating a seam. With the faces selected, go into edge mode, deselect the edge bridging the face then try bevelling again.

Comment: Thank you! Worked beautifully!